# Java read contents from a file and apply to formula

Tags: java, file, formula

Trying to read contents of a file and apply to a formula

e.g
if the file contains

> 7
>
> 9.50
>
> 1.25

the output would be

> €7.0 = £5.46
>
> €9.5 = £7.41
>
> €1.25 = £0.975

My Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fileQuestion {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

        File fileContents = new File("currencyFile.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fileContents);

        if(fileContents.exists() == false ) {
        System.out.println("File doesnt exist ");
        }

        else{

        while(inputFile.hasNextInt())
        {
            double result;
            double conversionRate = 0.78;

            result = ??  * conversionRate;
            System.out.println("£" + fileContents + " = €" + result);
        }
        inputFile.close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...and what is the question?

Comment: @Gearoid, just add in while loop following code:
 int currencyValue = scanner.nextInt();
result = currencyValue  * conversionRate;

Comment: BTW You pasted code having some interrest to 'int', and file has floats

Comment: @Jacek is right, you need use hasNextFloat() and nextFloat() approptiatly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just don't know how to read the file, right? It's easy. If you have used `Scanner` before, you should know that there is a method called `nextDouble` that  returns the next `double` value. You should use this method.

Just replace `??` with `inputFile.nextDouble()`.

However, there are a few more problems with your code.

- Since the file contains `double` values, use `hasNextDouble` instead of `hasNextInt`.
- You should check whether the file exists before creating the `Scanner`. Otherwise it will throw an exception.
- You shouldn't print `fileContents`. instead, you should put the value you got from the file in a variable, then print the variable.

Here's some code:

```
    File fileContents = new File("currencyFile.txt");


    if(!fileContents.exists()) {
        System.out.println("File doesn't exist ");
    }
    else{
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fileContents);
        while(inputFile.hasNextDouble())
        {
            double result;
            double conversionRate = 0.78;
            double currencyFrom = inputFile.nextDouble();
            result = currencyFrom  * conversionRate;
            System.out.println("£" + currencyFrom + " = " + "€" + result);
        }
        inputFile.close();

    }
```